# Do retailers ever stock goods just to make other goods sell better?

Tags: shopping

<sub>Perhaps this is too vague or off-topic... I hope not...</sub>

Are there any examples where retailers stock certain goods that they know won't sell very well, but will make *other* goods sell better, and so have an beneficial effect on sales overall? For instance, might a shop deliberately "waste" a bit of shelf space stocking some super-expensive shampoo, knowing that it won't sell much, but also knowing that their fairly-expensive shampoo will sell better because it looks like a bargain by comparison? Or do they simply seek to get all their stock sold?

Comment: Yes it happens. Read predictably irrational, and other marketing books.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a concept in retail called a "loss leader", and essentially it means that a store will sell an item intentionally at a loss as a way of bringing in business in the hope that while consumers are in the store taking advantage of the discounted item, they'll make other purchases to make up for the loss and generate an overall profit.

Many times it only makes sense to carry items that enhance the value of something else the store sells.  Stores pay big money to study consumer behaviors and preferences in order to understand what items are natural fits for each other and the best ways to market them.

A good example of what you're talking about is the fact that many grocery stores carry private label products that sell for higher margins, and they'll stock them alongside the name brands that cost much more.  As a consequence (and since consumers often don't see a qualitative difference between store brands and name brands much of the time to rationalize spending more), the store's own brands sell better.

I hope this helps.

Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

They may stock items that frame the various price points. Of course they risk having the items go stale before they are sold.

You also have situations where the store will advertise an item, but end up taking a loss on that sale because it will bring people in, and they will make other purchases.

Determining what to stock, how to display it, and how to advertise it involves both math and psychology.

Answer (score 3):

That happens all the time. The best situation for this to happen is when you have several products, each a bit better and a bit more expensive than the other, and you add a new product which is the cheapest. That gets people into the store to look at the cheapest product, and then you show the the next more expensive which is so much better for only a little more money, and the next more expensive which is again so much better... You might not sell any of the cheapest product but it helps you sell the others.

Also happens the other way round: You add a really expensive item, unaffordable for most customers, that is really, really nice. Then customers look at it and you show them that for half the price they can have something that is almost as nice. The expensive product increases the amount that customers think is "the right price" for that kind of product. A customer might think that $2,000 for a diamond ring is an awful lot of money, but if you show them another ring for $5,000 then suddenly the $2,000 doesn't look that expensive anymore. And if it is almost as nice as the $5,000 ring, you sell a lot of rings for $2,000 because you had the more expensive ring in the store.

Answer (score 1):

Use of this is demonstrated in this video:

https://youtu.be/Ip5jG3djdyk

Stocking products that you have no intention of selling can be used to make other products look more appealing by comparison. It's more psychological than anything but it isn't an uncommon practice.